# How does leaving out the display:table on the parent element affect layout when using the display:table-cell hack?

Tags: css, css-tables

I am using the `display: table-cell` hack on some navigation elements, [as here](http://imperavi.com/kube/css/navigation/#).  Previously, I have used `display: table` on the parent elements housing the `display: table-cell` elements, and have noticed that removing the `display: table` does not affect the layout.  I have consulted the [W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#value-def-table-cell), and it still remains unclear to me what role `display: table` plays aside from allowing vertical and horizontal centering, or [content re-ordering](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2013/06/css/css-stacking-with-display-table).

When using the `display: table-cell` hack, is it best to declare a rule `display: table` on the parent elements?  If not, how does this affect layouts in older browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't assign `display: table` to an ancestor of a `display: table-cell` element, it creates an [anonymous table (and table row) wrapper](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) around the cell as appropriate. From the subsection in the one you link to:

> 3. Generate missing parents:
>
>    1. For each 'table-cell' box C in a sequence of consecutive internal table and 'table-caption' siblings, if C's parent is not a 'table-row' then generate an anonymous 'table-row' box around C and all consecutive siblings of C that are 'table-cell' boxes.
>    2. For each proper table child C in a sequence of consecutive proper table children, if C is misparented then generate an anonymous 'table' or 'inline-table' box T around C and all consecutive siblings of C that are proper table children. (If C's parent is an 'inline' box, then T must be an 'inline-table' box; otherwise it must be a 'table' box.)
>
>       - A 'table-row' is misparented if its parent is neither a row group box nor a 'table' or 'inline-table' box.

These anonymous boxes cannot be targeted normally with CSS, nor can you control how and where to create them, by virtue of being anonymous. Neither can you make them inherit any non-inherited styles from the parent element.

Because anonymous table boxes are generated automatically, setting `display: table` is not always required. It is only necessary if your table-cell elements are parented by elements with layout properties, such as floating, clearance, or set dimensions (like `width: 100%`), and you need to make sure these properties apply directly to the table boxes, not the *parents* of those table boxes.

I'm not aware of any major layout issues in older browsers that implement `display: table` et al.